# Pulseaudio With SimpleScreenRecorder Problem

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I just installed SimpleScreenRecorder to record my screens with audio. SSR is working smoothly. Only problem is my voices are not recording with pullseaudio as Backend! When I record audio using ALSA I hear sounds but the sound is very very very noisy. On the other hand with Pulseaudio I simply don't hear even any pin drop sound. I guess my pulseaudio needs some treatment. How to solve the problem and how can I get smooth audio recording using SimpleScreenRecorder?

Comment: Hard to know from what little you posted. We need to know your hardware and what you are recording with. In general, however, if it is not working it is often helpful to use Ubuntu Studio as studio is set up for recording. Audio recording is very different from a standard desktop.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I am trying to record screen with audio. I have a headphone with microphone. Trying to record video from this. When I talk in skype my listeners don't report anything noisy. But when I try to record screen using SSR I really fail to record voice using the headphone! This is annoying. I am sure there are problems with my Ubuntu settings. Pulseaudio has problem indeed.

Comment: Not really sure it is a problem with pulse audio, the issues is that audio configuration is different from a typical desktop configuration. If the default desktop works, great, but if not I suggest you try ubuntu studio. If you want you can try installing and configuring jack and what not . See http://libremusicproduction.com/articles/advantages-choosing-audio-orientated-linux-distribution and http://wiki.linuxaudio.org/wiki/system_configuration

Comment: FWIW, with a properly configured system, recording works well with jack with or without pulseaudio. In the unlikely event of a conflict you can remove or disable pulse, but I have not recently had a problem with pulse audio (it is almost always a jack or system configuration problem)